# Article before nouns in appositive phrases

Tags: grammar

Just spotted out the following sentence on a webpage (web [link](https://www.mcsweeneys.net/articles/whats-an-appositive-charlie-brown))

*He hungered to kick it, the rubber bean-shaped pod, container of his coveted masculinity.*

May I ask why we put an article before the first appositive phrase, *rubber bean-shaped pod,* but omit it before the second one, *container of his coveted masculinity?*

Comment: Both the NPs *the rubber bean-shaped pod, container of his coveted masculinity* refer back to *it*. So, perhaps this rule  "when two or more adjectives qualify the same noun, the article is used only before the first adjective" has been followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the phrase between the paired commas to be nonessential, then its removal should result in something grammatical.

That is not the case here:

> He hungered to kick it *[, the rubber bean-shaped pod,]* container of his coveted masculinity.

If you remove the text in italics, the resulting sentence is ungrammatical.

---

A grammatical sentence would be:

> He hungered to kick it, the rubber bean-shaped pod, from his coveted masculinity.

Or, alternately:

> He hungered to kick it, the rubber bean-shaped or container, from his coveted masculinity.

Comment: Thanks Jason for the explanation and example sentences! In other words, may I ask if every individual oppositive must be preceded by an article?

Comment: It depends on the content: *He hungered to kick it, with its red cover, from his coveted masculinity.* *He hungered to kick it, and anything else like it, from his coveted masculinity.*

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to omit the second *the*, but its omission is allowed. My best guess is that this corresponds to the following case discussed in [Collins COBUILD English Guides: Articles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0003705617) (p. 71):

> Articles can be left out:
>
> • when two nouns (or adjectives), both acting as head of a noun group, are joined together with 'and' or 'or'; the second head can be without its article. This happens with both the definite and the indefinite article.
>
> *They had enhanced **the reliability and quality** of radio reception.
>
>   ...**a coffee cup and saucer**.
>
>   You can order traveller's cheques through **a local bank or travel
>   agent**.*
>
> You don't have to leave out the second article; you can say 'a coffee cup and a saucer'. But if you do leave it out, the two nouns must be closely related in meaning; you couldn't say 'There was a matchbox and jacket on the table'.

This would apply most obviously if the appositive was written as a **syndetic coordination**, i.e. one with an explicit coordinator:

*He hungered to kick it, the rubber bean-shaped pod **and** container of his coveted masculinity.*

In your sentence, for stylistic reasons the writer chose to use **asyndetic coordination**, which is marked by just a comma.